# Cookies & mulitple domains with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I have a website which creates a cookie and I want to use this cookie in my application on Facebook. is it possible? if not, any idea how to recieve information from my website and pass it to Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't share cookies across domains - just subdomains.  That's by design, and important (tm).

Answer (score 0):

Can you have the user log in to your site using Facebook Connect to share a session across the two sites?

Comment: I can use in seeseion too, there is a way to share a session?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Andy said, you can't share cookies across domains and this is an important security feature. Another thing you can't do is make cross-domain AJAX requests.

What's odd about your question is you're asking about a facebook application. Facebook applications are not hosted by facebook, so therefore you are hosting the application yourself. Since you are hosting the application yourself, it is possible you're hosting the application on the same server and even domain. Therefore if that is the case, as long as your facebook application is using an iframe and points to the application hosted on the same domain you can have cookies accessed from both the application and the website. But again, I repeat this is only if your facebook application is using an iframe and pointing to a domain that is the same as your website.

Tip: If your application or website is a subdomain, make sure to put a dot before your cookie to make it accessible on all subdomains. i.e. .domain.com